# NumberSign Key in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, keyevent, virtual-keyboard, on-screen-keyboard

I have created an onscreen keyboard. There is a key '-/+' which will serve to toggle change the number sign entered in number field. But i don't know can i create key event for this key. Following is my attempt but it is not working

```
void Onscreen Keyboard::btnNumSign_Clicked()
{
    QKeyEvent * event = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress,Qt::Key_NumberSign,Qt::NoModifier);
    QCoreApplication::postEvent(parentWidget()->focusWidget(),event);
}
```

Please tell how I can fix it.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: When I press sign('-/+') key, nothing is happning.Mean ideally sign of number should be change from - to + and vice versa

Comment: How exactly do you create your onscreen keyboard? Do you catch the key event after you fire it?

Comment: No, just fire Key event which automatically received and handled by Qt component. It’s like a keyboard simulator

Comment: Does `parentWidget()->focusWidget()` is the one you expect? Also try `QApplication::postEvent`, not `QCoreApplication` one

Comment: Also as I understand you have many other buttons on you keyboard. Does the similar code work for them?

Comment: yes all are working, except this '-/+' button